# Problems with my data saved with $_SESSION (Wordpress, ACF)

Tags: php, wordpress, session-variables

I have a question and hope you can help me.

I am creating a Wordpress theme, I am using **`ACF *(Advanced custom fields)*`** to save information in vars. For example:

**`home.php`** -> I am saving a lot of information in vars inside of this file.

I need to use this vars in another document for example:

**`store.php`**

I am not a PHP expert, for this reason, was easy for me use **`$_SESSION`** vars to save and use my information in all my files.

I have saved the vars in my **`home.php`** like this:

```
session_start();
ob_start();    
$name = $_SESSION['home_name'] = get_field('home_name');
```

I am trying to get the data on my **store.php** like this:

```
session_start();
ob_start();    
$name = $_SESSION['home_name'];
```

But I have seen a possible error.
Sometimes I cannot see the data of the var in my **`store.php`**.
To see the data again I need to open the **`home.php`** and later refresh **`store.php`**

Do you know why?
How can I solve this error?

If you know a best practice to save and sent my data I am really interested in learning.

Answer (score 1):

Variable assignments have no return value. When saving, try the following:

```
session_start();
ob_start();
$_SESSION['home_name'] = get_field('home_name');
$name = $_SESSION['home_name'];
```

Alternatively, you can make an alias to the `$_SESSION['home_name']` variable like so

```
$name &= $_SESSION['home_name'];
```

That way any changes you make to `$name`will be reflected on `$_SESSION['home_name']` and vice-versa.

Comment: Thanks Raphael de Oliveira let me confirm if I understand.

in my home.php I need to create my vars like this right?
`session_start();
ob_start();

$_SESSION['home_name'] = get_field('home_name');
$name &= $_SESSION['home_name'];`

and at my store.php how I need to take the data?

`$name &= $_SESSION['home_name'];`

Comment: You can access your data using `session_start(); $_SESSION['home name']`. The name will be stored in the `$_SESSION['home name']` variable.

Comment: Yes, @Raphael I have made that, but the problem is that to see the data on my second web page I need restart my first web page and later the second.

I think this person has the same problem than me:

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39890976/save-php-variable-in-wordpress-to-get-access-from-every-file?rq=1

Comment: Can you show us a `var_dump($_SESSION);` of when you load the first page for the first time?

Answer (score 1):

work with sessions was a mess for me, I found the best option to sent my var information from a file to another php file.

Is better use the post ID in our function get_field('var_nane', id);

```
$varName = get_field('field_name', 132);
```

Is different the post ID of our Advanced Custom Field Group than the id of where we are using this ACFG.

https://support.advancedcustomfields.com/forums/topic/how-to-change-the-scope-of-a-custom-field-group/#post-52629

https://www.advancedcustomfields.com/resources/get_field/